# How do I send user's wifi credentials to my RPI wirelessly?

Tags: wifi, boot, bluetooth, pi-zero, wifi-direct

I am working on a project which would require me to connect my Rpi 0 w to my home wifi. I want to send the pi wifi credentials(ssid and psk) over my phone the very first time and then on subsequent reboots, the pi should automatically connect to my home network. During this process, the pi wouldn't have access to monitor/keyboard/mouse.

The closest I came to achieve what I want was by following this:
https://imti.co/iot-wifi/#connect-the-p ... fi-network

But the above didn't automatically connect to wifi after a reboot.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set up a Pi headlessly. See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) *Headless Raspbian WiFi Setup*, although it is easier to use the Raspberry Pi Imager or a keyboard and screen.

Trying to automate this would be possible, but you would need to setup the Pi first and write code to do this.

Comment: How do I automate it this? I can setup the Pi one time

Comment: @PrarthanaPBhat This is a non-trivial task, which would require restarting networking. You will not find a ready made solution. You can configure the Pi to connect to different networks (mine is setup for 9) and it will connect to the highest priority available network.